# How to uninstall an application which was installed from a Linux Installer?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, mono, uninstall

My server is CentOS release 5.2 (Final).

How do I uninstall an application which was installed from a Linux Installer, that is extension of type *.bin*?

For example: I installed an application called [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) using [Linux Installer](http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/archive/1.2.4/linux-installer/6/mono-1.2.4_6-installer.bin) and now I want to uninstall this application.

If it's a RPM installation, we can use *'rpm -e'* and if it's installed from source we can use *'make uninstall'*.  Similarly, what is the equivalent way of uninstalling an application installed from a Linux Installer (.bin)?

**NOTE:** Mono is a cross platform, open source .NET development framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installers of this sort do not typically have a standard way of uninstalling themselves.  You'll want to refer to any documentation that came with the installer, or perhaps take a look for any README's it installed.  Some installers of that sort have an uninstall option, others install a binary/script that does the trick.

Speaking particularly of Mono, however, from what I can tell they offer RPMs/a Yum repository for RHEL/CentOS.  Was this installer a 3rd party product or is it a relic of an earlier way of doing things?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  This is an official Linux Installer from Mono (Novell) and not a 3rd party product.  I've even given a link for this Linux Installer in the question itself.

Comment: Thanks.  As you said, I could find "uninstall" binary file available in the Mono installation location `/opt/mono-1.2.4/uninstall`, which is used to uninstall Mono.  Am able to uninstall successfully.

Comment: @Gnanam, find / -name '*mono*'

Answer (score 0):

If the mono installer supports a "test install" where it doesn't write anything to disk, run it that way and pipe into a file the output of where it's putting all the files. Then feed that output into a rm -rf script.

You could also just reinstall, if you don't care about possibly screwing up your conf file. Then just write a simple bash script with a for() that reads every line in the output file and delete each file one by one.